# laravel homestead on windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, windows-10, homestead

When I tried to install laravel homestead I face problems
I use git terminal, when I try this

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
```

I get this error

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...

==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider:
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
    box:

An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found
```

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756769/laravel-homestead-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you should just update Vagrant. Your issue should be fixed with this commit: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/5f12126d32dfa30f5f48d12724eeb29222942cb0

---

If you do not want to update Vagrant, then solution is to uncomment this parameter in Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.box_check_update = false
```