# Laravel Homestead (Windows)

Tags: windows, laravel, vagrant, composer-php, homestead

Today I have been trying to install the Laravel library together with Laravel Homestead.. But I can't seem to get it working.

The first thing, Laravel documentation tells you to do: `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"`, but it didn't work.

So I searched the internet some and found: `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~3.0"`, which actually worked.

But now when I try to run the `homestead` command in my command line, it gives me this: http://prntscr.com/9perhj, that's the only thing it's giving me.

I have added the directory to my path variable.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do a `-1` if you don't even reply why.

Answer (score 0):

`Homestead` itself command will return this expected screen. You would need to pass the command you want to run.

At first, run `homestead init` so that it will create the `Homestead.yaml` configuration file

Comment: If I'm running `homestead init`, I get this in return: http://prntscr.com/9phz5c.. More errors :s

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I thought I'd put up my answer since it took me multiple tries to get it right and I documented the process while I was doing it so I wouldn't have such a hard time in the future.

Note: You should NOT have NginX, PHP, MySQL, etc. installed on your machine. The Vagrant Homestead virtual box provides all of this functionality. I had some issues where I had NginX and MySQL on my machine and it was connecting to my local machine's MySQL when it should be connecting to the virtual box's MySQL.

Without further ado, this is how I set it up for my Windows 7 machine:

1. Prerequisites:

   VirtualBox:

   ```
   https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
   ```

   Vagrant:

   ```
   https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
   ```

   Git Bash: A terminal that feels like a Linux terminal. You can do everything you do on an Ubuntu server in Windows.

   ```
   https://git-scm.com/downloads
   ```

   Putty: Telnet client that I used for connecting to my VirtualBox Homestead server

   ```
   http://www.putty.org/
   ```
2. create project folder
3. open terminal in project folder (something like E:\Projects\Vagrant)
4. type 'vagrant box add laravel/homestead'
5. type 'git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead'

   This installs Homestead in the designated project folder.
6. type 'cd Homestead'
7. type 'bash init.sh' OR 'init.bat'

   This creates a folder in:

   ```
   C:\Users\USERNAME\.homestead
   ```

   which has the file:

   ```
   Homestead.yaml
   ```

   If you open the Homestead.yaml file it should look something like this:

   ```
   ---
   ip: "192.168.10.10"
   memory: 2048
   cpus: 1
   provider: virtualbox

   authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

   keys:
       - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   folders:
       - map: ~/Code
         to: /home/vagrant/Code

   sites:
       - map: homestead.app
         to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

   databases:
       - homestead
   ```

   The '~/' folder is the equivalent of:

   ```
   C:\Users\USERNAME\
   ```

   Change:

   ```
   folders:
       - map: ~/Code
         to: /home/vagrant/Code

   sites:
       - map: homestead.app
         to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
   ```

   To:

   ```
   folders:
       - map: E:/Projects/Vagrant/Homestead
         to: /home/vagrant/Homestead

   sites:
       - map: WEBSITE.dev
         to: /home/vagrant/Homestead/Laravel/public
   ```
8. goto C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
9. open the file 'hosts' in a text editor

   add '192.168.10.10 WEBSITE.dev' (the IP address should match the IP address in the Homestead.yaml file)
10. open a terminal in E:/Projects/Vagrant/Homestead folder
11. type 'ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "USERNAME@gmail.com"'

    This creates the folder C:\Users\USERNAME.ssh and sets up your SSH Key
12. type 'vagrant init laravel/homestead'
13. type 'vagrant up'

    You should see Homestead running in VirtualBox

    You can use 'vagrant destroy' to kill it when done
14. Use putty.exe to log in to Homestead

    IP Address: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 2222

    login as: vagrant
    password: vagrant

Everything is now ready